# Change email "anonymous" sent from my website

Tags: php, email

I'm having an issue with a contact form. The email message is correctly sent but in my inbox appears as "From: anonymous@web.godns.net" and not "From: web@mywebsite.com", and goes directly to SPAM.

I've been looking for similar issues but no one gives the specific answer. I guess if the code is having a syntax mistake or it's a server problem.

This is the PHP file:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  http_response_code(500);
  exit();
}

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Mensaje Web de >> $name";
$body = "Recibiste mensaje a través del formulario en la web.\n"."Estos son los datos:\n\nNombre y Apellido: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nTeléfono: $phone\n\nTexto del mensaje:\n$message";
$headers= "From: web@mywebsite.com" . "\r\n" . 
    "Reply-To: $email \r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
if(!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
  http_response_code(500);
?>
```

Does anyone figure out what's wrong here?
Thank you,

Alejandra | aleare.design

Answer (score 0):

It may solve your problem or not but it's always a good idea to set a proper sender address. In [good old `mail()`](https://php.net/mail) that needs to be done with the `$additional_parameters` parameter and the syntax is `-f` followed by an email address with no display name:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-fweb@mywebsite.com')
```

Additionally, make sure that your local SMTP server allows sending messages in the name of `web@mywebsite.com`. If it doesn't, perhaps you need to get another server and make use of authentication, something that `mail()` doesn't allow.

In any case, it's really hard to get email right with this function since you need to do everything by yourself and email protocol is not trivial. For instance, I think your code is vulnerable to [email headers injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection). It's easier to just use a third-party library like Swift Mailer or PHPMailer.

P.S. What are you trying to accomplish with `strip_tags(htmlspecialchars())`? This will just make user input unreadable for not obvious gain.

Comment: Basically he is trying to create a contact form. The contact form contain such as customer name, email, phone, and message. Just like ordinary contact form. So his admin/PIC could follow up back the whoever the person who type in the form.

so the ``strip_tags(htmlspecialchars())`` are supposed to strip all the html attributes, only left the message/text the person type in.

Comment: @aleare.design Then, unless there's a typo I overlooked, it all points to a restriction imposed by your hosting service. Perhaps that's something you can clarify with their support team.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you, I don't get it why you put so many text in the header

`// Create the email and send the message
$to = "youremail@yourdomain.com"; // Add your email address inbetween the " " replacing username@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$header = "From: noreply@adamar.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$header .= "Reply-To: $email";` `// this is to automatically reply to your correspondent email rather than your noreply email, I separate it from your header.`

also mind to change the variable $headers to $header? Maybe it might help. Wish all the best of it. Cheers!

Comment: have you tried to copy and paste the code? try to find out the condition. If it didn't solve the problem. Please try to contact your hosting server services. Because I just tried the code, and it works.